# How to run ShellExecute on shell object clsid?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-explorer, windows-shell

Shell explorer on Windows define global objects such as ::{2559a1f4-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0 which is a link to the user "internet browser". I got these value from a shortcut that is drag&dropped over my application, but I can't find how to use it to open it...

I'd like to get information about what this object is too.

- Does someone know how to ask Windows about what this object is ?
- Does someone know how to open it ?

I have found that these objects can be found by reading from the registry at :

```
initString = HLCR\CLSID\\{CLSID\}\PersistentBag\InitString
openCommand = HKLM\Software\Clients\{initString}\shell\open\command
```

Usually its not a good idea to read directly from the registry. I'd be please to have a cleaner way to read these values.

Thanks.

Comment: {2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0} is Run (Win+R) as far as I can tell

Comment: @anders : you're right, I poked around the registry and copy the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to fill in a SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure, with the fMask field set to SEE_MASK_CLASSKEY, the lpVerb field set to "open" and the lpClass set to your GUID.

However, I never got the damn thing to work. Instead I used a file of the correct type to use in a CreateProcess call.

```
    HINSTANCE h = FindExecutable("blank.htm", NULL, buffer);

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char url[MAX_PATH];
    sprintf(url, "\"%s\" %s", buffer, (LPCTSTR)m_url);
    CreateProcess(NULL, url, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0 , NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Which opens the app that is defined as the default viewer for files of type .htm.

Comment: I really need to execute any of these links, not just the "internet browser" one. I'll try your first tip though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From "Creating Shell Extensions with Shell Instance Objects" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997573.aspx it is told that

*Whereas a traditional shell extension requires a DLL to implement the object, a shell instance object retrieves everything it needs to know from the registry.*

It seems to be safe to read the informations from the registry as it is the documented solution to create them.